# Scrapy close spider if no urls to crawl

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a spider which takes url from a redis list.

I want to close spider nicely when there is no url found. I tried to implement `CloseSpider` exception, but it seems that it doesn't reach this point

```
def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        item = json.loads(self.__pop_queue())
        if not item:
            raise CloseSpider("Closing spider because no more urls to crawl")
        try:
            yield scrapy.http.Request(item['product_url'], meta={'item': item})
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Even though i am raising the CloseSpider exception but I am still getting the below error:

```
root@355e42916706:/scrapper# scrapy crawl general -a country=my -a log=file
2017-07-17 12:05:13 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/scrapper/scrapper/spiders/GeneralSpider.py", line 20, in start_requests
    item = json.loads(self.__pop_queue())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Moreover, I also tried to catch TypeError in the same function but it doesn't work also.

Is there any recommended way to handle this

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if `self.__pop_queue()` returns something before you give it to `json.loads()` (or capture the `TypeError` when calling it), something like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        item = self.__pop_queue()
        if not item:
            raise CloseSpider("Closing spider because no more urls to crawl")
        try:
            item = json.loads(item)
            yield scrapy.http.Request(item['product_url'], meta={'item': item})
        except (ValueError, TypeError):  # just in case the 'item' is not a string or buffer
            continue
```

Comment: @BLANQUERAdrien - Rise a question of your own and post your code / error and we'll see what's going on, this is more tailored to the OPs problem with gracefully exiting his generator function.

Comment: @zwer Thanks it is working as expected now. One thing i am still confuse about. At what point we can catch the spiders exceptions. I mean in terms of scrapy framework what is the standard ? Thanks

Comment: @RaheelKhan - There really is no standard when it comes to errors that you 'generate' (like in the case above) - although non-Scrapy errors should be propagated to your main script. You can use `errback` argument when creating a request to have it call your custom function when it encounters an error and then you can choose how to manage it. You can also call the same function when you want to 'issue' a custom error so that you have everything central.

Comment: got it ! Thanks bro

Comment: @zwer Just wondering if you have experience using tor with scrapy ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan - can't say I do, but there shouldn't be much difference given that Scrapy is happy to use proxies and Tor provides a classic proxy interface. The only issue I can think of is that .onion links don't really follow all the standard URI guidelines so they might confuse request parsing but that shouldn't be too difficult to supplement.

Comment: I am not scraping .onion but for normal sites with tor middleware i am getting the cloudfare captcha page in response. Anyways i got the idea. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found a little trick. When the spider is in **idle** (when it does nothing), I check if there is still something left in the redis queue. If not I close the spider with `close_spider`. The following code is located in the `spider` class:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
    from_crawler = super(SerpSpider, cls).from_crawler
    spider = from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider.idle, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_idle)
    return spider


def idle(self):
    if self.q.llen(self.redis_key) <= 0:
        self.crawler.engine.close_spider(self, reason='finished')
```

Comment: This is informative bro. Havent used signals yet. Thanks